# Is there a cleaner way to test extras_require

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, dependency-management

I have code reviewed a piece of Python code, but to me it looks really ugly, hacky and complex for something that can be achieved very easily.

The code looks something similar to the following:

`_extra.py` (this is supposed to be a private module because of the underscore):

```
import dependency

class Extra(dependency.Cls):
    ...
```

`setup.py`

```
setup(
    ...
    name='somepkg',
    extras_require={
        ...
        'extra': ['dependency']})
```

`public.py`

```
_dist = pkg_resources.working_set.find(
    pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('somepkg'))

if 'extra' in _dist:
    from _extra import Extra
```

So that the extras_require can be tested using:

```
class ExtraTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    # Some test cases where the requirement actually is available

    def test_require_extra(self):
        dist = mock.Mock(pkg_resources.Distribution)
        self.dist.extras = []
        public = helper.import_or_reload('public')
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            public.Extra
```

My initial thought would be to not have `_extra.py` exist and have `public.py` look like:

```
try:
    import dependency
except ImportError
    pass
else:
    class Extra(dependency.Cls):
        ...
```

I don't really care that it isn't tested that it can't be imported if it is not in the `extras_require`.

Does the original code seem like a logical solution?
Should `extras_require` be tested in any way? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all done just to make it possible to test the `Extra` class, then the code is overcomplicating matters. The code is asking for permission rather than for forgiveness.

You are quite correct, changing the code to catch the `ImportError` exception would vastly simplify the codebase.

The code shouldn't even try to test the detection, but simply rely on Python's own unit tests to have tested throwing an `ImportError` properly. At best the unittest should verify what happens if `extra` is not set (perhaps by the code setting `extra = None` if the dependency is missing, testing is then as easy as mocking `extra = None`).